# Dynamic sql-statement in Ms Access

Tags: ms-access

say there is a list. I want to inject values from the selected record to an sql-statement. Actually I do that with vba:

1. trigger the update-event for the listbox
2. generate the sql-string (with vba)
3. send the sql-string to the control

Question: Is it possible to do with the visual editor only?

Comment: As you will use VBA, the VBE (editor) is the tool to use.

Comment: I am asking for a solution without using VBA code. I just need to set the filter from one listbox, when the user selects a entry in another listbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer to form controls in SQL statements using the `Forms!FormName!ControlName` syntax.

This should allow you to construct the SQL string without needing VBA, but you do need to manually requery to see the change. That can either be achieved with embedded macros or VBA.

Comment: One question before I try that. Can a refer to the form that stores this logic? Must be something like "me!", not?

Comment: @doev You can try using `Screen.ActiveForm!ControlName`, but that increases the chance for weirdness, for example, if you have other forms that modify your form using VBA code. The database engine is unaware of the form executing the query, so no, you can't use `Me.`

Comment: thank you. The solution works fine for simple sql statements.

Comment: Maybe you should add that this doesn't work with multiselect boxes.